# Analysis of solutions to an equation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, trigonometry

I have the following equation:
Ntan(x) = tan(Nx) for x belongs to 0 to pi (exclusive).
How can I find the number of solutions to this equation for some natural number N (N > 1) **without a graphical approach**?
The answer should be N-2.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.

Comment: hint: look when both sides are equal to zero

Comment: $3 \tan (x)-\tan (3 x)=0\to -\frac{8 \sin ^2(x) \tan (x)}{2 \cos (2 x)-1}=0$ has no solutions in $(0,\pi)$. I'd say $N>3$

Comment: Do you consider $\tan\frac \pi2$ defined? if so, how? If not, all odd $N$ may give you problems